# How to force a crawler to update a specific table?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am currently sending logging records through a firehose delivery stream that formats the records to parquet by using a table defined in my glue catalog for the schema of the parquet file. Lets call this table `log_table`. The formatted records are then stored in an S3 bucket.

The issue I am running into is that when I try to crawl the data found in the s3 buckets, instead of updating the `log_table`, it creates a new table with the name `log_table_<some random string>`. How do I force the crawler to update that specific table?

A lot of posts here talk about setting certain properties for the crawler related to combining related schemas,  using custom classifiers, and even setting a glue table property to `UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER` but none of these have seemed to work.

Currently the delivery stream, glue table, glue crawler are created via Cloudformation.

The delivery stream format conversion is configured as such.

`DataFormatConversionConfiguration:
          Enabled: True
          InputFormatConfiguration:
            Deserializer:
              OpenXJsonSerDe:
                CaseInsensitive: True
          OutputFormatConfiguration:
            Serializer:
              ParquetSerDe:
                Compression: SNAPPY
          SchemaConfiguration:
            CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
            RoleARN: !GetAtt DeliveryStreamRole.Arn
            DatabaseName: !Ref GlueDatabase
            TableName: !Ref TransactionLogsTable
            Region: !Ref AWS::Region
            VersionId: LATEST`

The crawler is created with default settings (name,role,s3 target, etc.)
Likewise for the glue table.

I want the crawler to update the `log_table` that I used to tell my delivery stream what the schema of the parquet file should be.

Comment: Does default settings of your crawler set 'Create a single schema for each S3 path' to true?

Comment: @IlyaKisil I have tried that and it doesn't work.